# Страницу на печать angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть условно говоря заказ все данные хранятся в БД Как под средством angularjs не открывая вид а передать скажем передать в функцию orderPrint идентификатор заказа и что бы уже потом по шаблону собралась страница и открылась страница печати.

Comment: Может я что-то не понимаю, но что такое orderPrint и при чем тут angular?

Comment: поставлю вопрос иначе. Есть список с заказами при нажатии на кнопку печать должна произойти магия ПОКА ДЛЯ МЕНЯ и открытся страница печати без всяких видов. только див. orderPrint  эта как пример функция которая может получить все данные заказа из БД вот и встаёт вопрос как отправить страницу на печать.

Comment: Уточнения к вопросу следует делать с помощью нажатия на кнопку "править". Кнопка *печать* где: в меню браузера или на странице? Может у Вас вообще не браузер, а приложение на мобильном? Что значит страница без всяких видов? Может вы вообще хотите создать *PDF* документ на сервере и его печатать? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: именно "Может вы вообще хотите создать PDF документ на сервере и его печатать? Уточните вопрос" В браузере по нажатию на кнопку.